# STM32: is SWD enabled?

Tags: c, stm32

I use a STM32G431CB, where the SWD-Pins are "dual use" in ym PCB design.
If I close two jumpers, both SWD-Pins can be used as GPIO Outputs, which will drive 2 LEDs.
During Development, Test & Debug these two jumpers are open and the ST-Link Debugger is connected.
This works fine so far.

The question is: is there any #define I could check for with "#ifdef" oder "#ifndef" if the SWD is enabled in the MCU setup or not? I went throuhg all the header files, but could not find a define (or something comparable) which I could use IMHO.

The Plan is to write some pieces of code like this:

```
#ifndef SWD_ENABLED
 DoSomethingWithTheLED_GPIO();
#endif
```

The effect should be:
as long as I have enabled SWD (at compile time) the functions, that Write the LED GIPOs are ignored. When I disable SWD in the MCU setup, the LEDs should be written.

But I don't know which #SYMBOL I could check on.

Answer (score 1):

```
DoSomethingWithTheLED_GPIO();
```

In this function, you will have to configure pins to be used in the modes you need. Those pins are simple configured as debug pins after the boot.

> The question is: is there any #define I could check for with "#ifdef"
> oder "#ifndef" if the SWD is enabled in the MCU setup or not?

No, there are no such defines.
But you can easily check if the pin is in "debug" configuration by checking `MODER & ARFL(H)` registers

Answer (score 0):

Which way do you use to

> ... disable SWD in the MCU setup, ...

In my projects I use global project `#define` that is used both to change setup code (set SWD pins to desired mode) and enable/disable the code which uses those pins.

Comment: yes, I have this approach now too. But it would have been handy, if there is allready a #define set by CubeIDE, I could check for. So I don't have to remember to set the Symbols by myself, but it works "automatically"

Comment: Got it. I use my own Makefile that is the root of project-level defines and places them into CFLAGS,

Comment: I use the Build Configurations for the Project in CubeIDE, where I define "SWD_ENABLED" as global Symbol for the (predefined) "Debug" and "Release" Build Configurations. Then I added another Build Configuration called "Release_Final", which does not have the "SWD_ENABLED" Symbol. So when I have finished debugging I can build "Release_Final", flash it and SWD is disabled and the GPIOs are used for the LEDs.